# How to muffle a small speaker

Tags: speakers

So I have a sump pump in my basement. When the power goes out, it will beep to let you know the power is out. I plan on going out of town for a couple of weeks

My wife will not go down into the basement at all. She wants me to unplug the pump which I don’t want to do

How can I muffle the speaker to where it’s almost silent?

Comment: Have your wife have someone to come in that will go down.  A non working sump pump is not good.  I imagine the beep is there to let you know there is a problem that could get bad.

Comment: What's the use of a device that beeps when the power goes off? Surely in a power cut a) you'll be perfectly aware because… it's a power cut & b) you'll have some irritating beeping to tell you what you already know… which you can do nothing about until the power comes back on :\ *…or am I missing something, somewhere?*

Comment: @Tetsujin Power may not be *fully cut* to the house, but just to *the sump circuit* which should have nothing else on it. Beeping lets the homeowner know that it's running on battery power in case they can do something about it before catastrophe happens. Battery systems also beep when the battery is low on power or the lead-acid battery needs refilled with distilled water.

Comment: @FredricShope - *"Power may not be fully cut to the house"* - really? I honestly don't get how that could happen, other than a fault which could trip a breaker… but how often is that going to happen? I don't think we've had a trip here in 20 years & I caused that one;) If it has a battery that needs topping up once a blue moon [& who has batteries that need that any more?]  why not check it before going away?

Comment: Tell your wife to wear earplugs while you are away?

Comment: i tone down annoying beepers with poster putty. Usually it's not a speaker, but a piezo buzzer, which looks like a small black cylinder with a 1mm hole centered at the end. Shove a pea-size amount of putty onto the end to bury the hole. It will be about 1/16th as loud after. If it is a speaker cone, soak cotton balls in warm Vaseline and shove into a zip-lock bag which you then cram around the speaker enclosure opening (that recipe won a science Olympiad trying to muffle a speaker).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how its located and how big the pump is. An inverted bucket could muffle it a little. Otherwise try sticking bandaid or plaster on it. And simulate a power fail to test.